# Записать 2 списка в один файл

Tags: python, list

Имеется два списка: `columns`, `strings`
Как записать их в файл построчно?
Код генерирует файлы и записывает только 1 список.

```
def write_file(columns, strings):
    for i in range (1,5):
        file_name = 'file{}.txt'.format(i)
        with open(file_name,'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(columns, file)
```

как записать их в файл построчно?
т.е.
файл должен иметь вот такой вид

```
['1 марта 1881 года. Казнь императора Александра II', 'документы и воспоминания']
['Заглавие', 'Свед.отн.к загл', 'Свед.об ответ.']
```

Comment: использовать переменную strings в функции write_file каким-то образом, очевидно. А не просто передавать ее туда и ничего с ней не делать.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы не показали содержание списков, можно только гадать, что вы хотели что-то такое (параллельно перебрать два списка через `zip`):

```
def write_file(columns, strings):
    for i, (c, s) in enumerate(zip(columns, strings), 1):
        file_name = f'file{i}.txt'
        with open(file_name,'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(f'{c}\n')
            file.write(f'{s}\n')
```